# Understanding XSS

Tags: xss, javascript, html

So, I am trying to understand how XSS works and I gathered some information online and crafted the code. Following is the snippet. When I enter some value in the text field and submit, the script should get exected.

```
<form action="http://randomsite/temp.php" onsubmit="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test" value='"></input><script>function alrt(){alert();} document.forms[0].setAttribute("onsubmit", "alrt()");</script><br'>
</form>
```

While the above code works, I do not understand why. 
Specifically, I do not understand the single quotation in ***value='">***. I also do not understand the ending break tag with a single quotation. I am not very proficient in JS so I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: *"While the above code works, ..."* - it does not work for me, neither on Firefox nor Chrome. It just displays `"></input><script>function alrt(){alert();} document.forms[0].setAttribute("onsubmit", "alrt()");</script><br` inside the text field. It only works if it starts with `value=''` but not `value='"`.

Comment: That's interesting. Because when I change it to value=' ', it doesn't work for me. I'm testing this on IceWeasel

Comment: IceWeasel was the former branding of Firefox by Debian but this is no longer done since 2016. This suggests for me that you are not using an up-to-date browser. What version number is displayed?

Comment: It is ESR 45.4.0

Comment: Firefox/IceWeasel ESR 45 is no longer supported. Version 45.4.0 was more than two years ago. Maybe the behavior changed.

Comment: Could be. But I don't understand why a break tag is required for the attack to work. Also, why does it not work when I replace the single quotes with double quotes? If it is just aesthetic, it should not matter.

Comment: I've tried with Firefox ESR 45.4.0 and your example still does not work, it only works when using `value=''...` and not with `value='"...`.  *"Also, why does it not work when I replace the single quotes with double quotes?"* - It will also work with `value=""...`.  Given that we have so different experiences with the code I have the feeling that the code you have in your question is not exact the same  and complete code as you are using to test yourself or that you are testing differently. I've just took above code, put it into a HTML file and opened this file with the browser.